# Laravel Forge Github Repository Error

Tags: github, laravel-forge

I am trying to connect my Laravel Forge (digitalocean) server to my Github repo like I've done many times in the past, however, this time it is giving an error saying

```
You must specify a repository to clone.
```

However, when I go into the command line and do a git clone of the branch and repository, it works fine. Any ideas what might cause this? I have my SSH key for Forge added to Github already.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the site on forge and reinstalling and it works now. Not sure exactly why it wasn't recognizing the repository, but it works now.